# How to store three small numbers in less than three variables

Tags: math

Can, by any manipulation, three natural numbers be stored in less than 3 variables?

Suppose we have three numbers each in the range 0-150, for example: 255, 12, 67. Numbers are not related to each other.

Now for storing them we need three variables or an array, but can by any mathematical manipulation these numbers be stored in 2 variables?

Comment: If you can bound the number of bits on the numbers, then you can certainly store it in one variable depending on how many bits you need...

Comment: If you cannot bound the number of bits, then even an infinite number of variables will not be enough to store one number.

Comment: With the proper encoding code *for the current actual values*, you can store everything even in 1 bit. But it will fail with other values, so that´s not what you want. SOoe generic compression algorithms may give you 33% less size, but again not with every input. Just use a bigger variable, a byte array etc.

Comment: @merlin2011 I have the range of numbers with me suppose they lie in between 0 to 150 but the numbers are not related to each other can it be done.

Comment: Yes, kilnan's answer is one solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? This looks like an XY Problem. Do you *actually* want to store numbers using as little *memory* as possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematical manipulations (data compression). To make it on-topic consider specifying data types of variables mentioned and/or including (pseudo)code to illustrate the particular problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can, but it depends on the range of the three numbers...

If you know that you're storing in a unsigned type with 2 bytes, you would have 16 bits, so
with a pattern of this kind

```
aaaabbbbbccccc0
```

You would be able to store 3 numbers of 5 bits. You can retrieve the value by shifting or dividing: using the above pattern it would be

```
a = n / (2^11)
b = (n % 2^11) / 2^6
c = (n % 2^6) / 2
```

where

- n is the variable
- % is used to cut out leftmost bits
- division is used to cut out rightmost bits (it must be an integer
  division, of course)

Answer (score 5):

You can store three natural numbers `a`, `b`, `c` as

```
x = 2^a * 3^b * 5^c
```

To retrieve the original numbers, you can make a prime factorization of `x` and find `a` as the exponent of `2`, `b` as the exponent of `3` and `c` as the exponent of `5`.

This way you can store infinitely many natural numbers within one natural number by making use of more primes. To make sure you do not lose information, you might want to use a `BigInt` class for arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: And horribly inefficient. The (2^a) part is known as unary encoding, which is bad enough. The other parts are even worse.

Answer (score 3):

You can obviously store three numbers in one variable of appropriate class type. If your intention is to store the three numbers with exact maximum values in as few bits as possible, then in c++ and c at least, there is a *bit field* syntax:

```
struct S {
    unsigned int a : 8;
    unsigned int b : 4;
    unsigned int c : 7;
};
S s {255,12,67};
```

Any types size must be divisible by byte size though, so you can't fit those example numbers in less than 3 bytes without extreme trickery. The compiler will pad the structure to at least nearest byte or possibly stricter alignment if it optimizes for speed.

If your language doesn't support bit fields, you'll have to do the math manually, like in other answers.

Comment: How is this solution not using 3 variables?

Comment: @ifLoop I'm giving a solution for a problem behind the question, not the question itself. I suspect that this is a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because nobody needs to store 3 numbers in less than 3 variables, ever.

Comment: I see your point, but I think this should rather be a comment than an answer.

Comment: @ifLoop After reading the question again, OP doesn't ask how to store the numbers by *using* less than 3 variables, they ask how to *store* the numbers in less than 3 variables. I would argue that the numbers are stored in the `s` variable and the bit field identifiers `a`, `b` and `c` can be used to reference the numbers. Bit fields are not once referred to as variables in the standard. Furthermore, even if we consider the bit fields as variables, my answer is not any more wrong or off topic than ziggystar's suggestion to use `BigInt` which uses several variables internally.

Comment: And (sorry, this is off topic, should probably belong to meta) I disagree with that answers on SO should mechanically follow every word of the question to the letter. The title *Efficient storage of three numbers* suggests that OP (and anyone arriving here, looking for information) may be also interested in a practical solution to a real problem rather than just superficially correct answer to a theoretical question.

Comment: Ok you convinced me, I agree to that point of view! If you edit your answer I will be able to change my vote :)

Comment: @ifLoop there you go :) You are free to change your vote now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others proposed, I would present one more aspect.
It depends on range of values to store per number. What if, for first value, the range is `250 - 255`only, then you just need 3 bits (since value is just `0` to `5`). While saving and/or retrieving you can add/subtract to `250`.

As another example, he other value (`12`) might just be saying 2nd multiplication of `2` (i.e. `6*2`). And you might have limited the range there also (`6-120`, for instance) - further reducing the bits needed!